# ASP.NET Web Pages 2 Select Value Validation

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-webpages

I figure this must be so simple and I'm missing something really obvious. I want to validate the selected value of a select input on an ASP.NET Web Pages 2 form using the built in validators but it doesn't look possible so far.

For example:

```
Validation.Add("my-select", Validator.ValueEquals("Some Value"));
```

Where `Validator.ValueEquals` would compare the selected value to the supplied parameter value "Some Value". I realize I could do:

```
if(Request["my-select"] != "Some Value") {
  Validation.AddFormError("Invalid option selected");
}
```

But then I don't have the error message associated with the field and it will only appear if I'm rendering the validation summary at the top of the form.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I've cracked the code! Unfortunately the solution is outside of the scope of the built in Validation and Validators static methods but I was able to achieve what I needed by using the following in place of the using the Validation class.

```
if(Request["my-select"] != "Some Value") {
  ModelState.AddError("my-select", "Invalid option selected");
}
```

Then check if the `ModelState` is valid when checking `Validation.IsValid()`:

```
if(ModelState.IsValid && Validation.IsValid()) {
  // More codes...
}
```

It's kind of cool that ModelState is available but it really seems clunky that this isn't handled by the `Validation` and `Validator` classes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [EqualsTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.validator.equalsto%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) validator and compare the supplied value to a hidden field value, or if you are worried that users might tamper with the hidden field value, you can write your own custom validator. I've blogged how to do that: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/195/ASP.NET-Web-Pages-Creating-Custom-Validators